# Does docker-compose version 1.29.1 support the --gpus parameter?

Tags: docker-compose

Does docker-compose version 1.29.1 support the --gpus parameter? If not, are there other parameters that support setting up the use of gpu in docker-compose 1.29.1 ?

Answer (score 7):

`--gpus` argument works with `docker` command. For `docker-compose` GPU configuration is done within `docker-compose.yml`:

#### Using the `runtime` option (legacy `v2.3` format)

```yaml
version: "2.3"
services:
  test:
    image: nvidia/cuda:10.2-base
    command: nvidia-smi
    runtime: nvidia # <- this option
```

#### Using the `device` structure (since docker-compose v1.28.0)

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  test:
    image: nvidia/cuda:10.2-base
    command: nvidia-smi
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
          - driver: nvidia
            # that's the closest analogue to --gpus; provide
            # an integer amount of devices or 'all'
            count: 1
            # Devices are reserved using a list of capabilities, making
            # capabilities the only required field. A device MUST 
            # satisfy all the requested capabilities for a successful 
            # reservation.
            capabilities: [gpu]
```

The latter might seem a bit complicated but there is a guide the explains both ([Enabling GPU access with Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gpu-support/#enabling-gpu-access-to-service-containers)
) and some extra information can be obtained from [The Compose Specification](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/deploy.md#devices).